# Displaying inline forms for all related objects in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to create a flexible app for managing surveys. What I would like to have is a 
**view** that displays all questions, options and follow-up questions related to a survey. I have the following models:

```
class Survey(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=300)

class Question(models.Model):
   question_text = models.CharField(max_length=300)
   belongs_to_survey = models.ForeignKey('Survey', related_name='questions') 
   follow_up_to_answer = models.ForeignKey('Question', null=True, related_name='follow_up_questions')

class Option(models.Model):
   answer_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   belongs_to_question = models.ForeignKey('Question', related_name='options')
```

I have looked into inlineformset_factory, but this only allows "one level of nesting". What I have is theoretically "infinite"

```
Survey -> Questions -> Options -> Follow-up-Questions -> Options --\
                                             ^\____________________/
```

Am I doing something wrong? As far as I can see this problem should be common, but the number of questions here on stackoverflow and other places suggests otherwise.

Comment: So you're looking to be able to edit all the questions and follow up questions for a survey, correct? Are you using a ModelForm?

Comment: Correct, @czarchaic. Yes, let's say I'm using a ModelForm for each of the models.

Comment: I can't quite get what nesting you talking about. If you have follow_up_to_answer in Question model, then why not use question id in  certain survey, for ordering them.
If following question depends on Option (or answer for the previous question), why follow_up_to_answer is Question's field and not Option's?

Answer (score 0):

Use `inlineformset_factory` twice:

1. To display `Question` instances for `Survey`
2. To display `Option` instances for each `Question`

Then, in the template display forms in the way that `option_formset` instances are printed after each `form` of `question_formset`.

Comment: Well, this would have to be done recursively to display each level of nesting. Because each `Option` can have a new `follow_up_question` giving a possibly infinite nesting of options and questions.